# Django installation in virtualenv : MySQL-python error

Tags: django, python-2.7, virtualenv, mysql-python

I'm trying to install Djando in a Python2.7 virtualenv on an OpenSuse 15.0
Installation of django works, but not of MySQL-python : [Djando installation documentation](https://django-story.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/003.installation.html)

```
pip install MySQL-python

Collecting MySQL-python
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/e9/51b544da85a36a68debe7a7091f068d802fc515a3a202652828c73453cad/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Building wheels for collected packages: MySQL-python
  Building wheel for MySQL-python (setup.py) ... error
  Complete output from command /home/u372284/development/pra_manager/djando/venv/bin/python2 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-4TF6HJ/MySQL-python/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-aVaY0z --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
  copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  running build_ext
  building '_mysql' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
  gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -fmessage-length=0 -grecord-gcc-switches -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -g -DNDEBUG -fmessage-length=0 -grecord-gcc-switches -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -g -DOPENSSL_LOAD_CONF -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/mariadb -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o
  _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_ping’:
  _mysql.c:2005:41: error: ‘MYSQL {aka struct st_mysql}’ has no member named ‘reconnect’
    if ( reconnect != -1 ) self->connection.reconnect = reconnect;
                                           ^
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I tried to install many libs : python-devel, mysqlclient, ... but nothing changed.

Someone know what's wrong ?

Comment: Unfortunatly it is :
`Information for package gcc:
----------------------------
Repository     : openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Oss   
Name           : gcc                      
Version        : 7-lp150.1.50             
Arch           : x86_64                   
Vendor         : openSUSE                 
Installed Size : 0 B                      
Installed      : Yes (automatically)      
Status         : up-to-date               
Source package : gcc-7-lp150.1.50.src     
Summary        : The system GNU C Compiler
Description    :                          
    The system GNU C Compiler.`

Comment: If you are using MySQL with Django today, the recommended library is `mysqlclient` instead of `MySQL-python`. Those installation instructions are very old. If you are learning Django today, please look for a different guide that uses Python 3 and Django 2.X.

Comment: Thanks @Alasdair ! I wanted to do it well with the official documentation :P

Answer (score 0):

if you wants to connect your djago with mysql you have to install mysql connector 5.6 or above version.

Django supports MySQL 5.6 and higher.

Django’s inspectdb feature uses the information_schema database, which contains detailed data on all database schemas.

Django expects the database to support Unicode (UTF-8 encoding) and delegates to it the task of enforcing transactions and referential integrity. It is important to be aware of the fact that the two latter ones aren’t actually enforced by MySQL when using the MyISAM storage engine, see the next section.